# Moq: getting values back from ref parameters in test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Given this function reference

```
void ParseFirstTwoRows(FileQueue file, ref string[] firstRow, ref string[] secondRow);
```

How can I use Moq to frame a test that relies on firstRow and secondRow having a value?

I've tried this:

```
Mock<IFileParser> mockFileParse = new Mock<IFileParser>();

string[] firstline = new string[2] { "1", "2" };
string[] secondline = null;

mockFileParse.Setup(m => m.ParseFirstTwoRows(It.IsAny<FileQueue>(), ref firstline, ref secondline))
                .Callback<FileQueue, string[], string[]>((fq, fl, sl) =>
                {
                    fq = new FileQueue();
                    fl = firstline;
                    sl = secondline;
                });

return mockFileParse;
```

But this results in the error:

> Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters
>   (FileQueue,String[]&,String[]&) cannot invoke callback with parameters
>   (FileQueue,String[],String[]).

I have seen several question on this, but I am confused as to whether what I'm trying to do is impossible, or whether I'm just not framing the test correctly. All I need for my tests is to ensure that the ref parameters have a value in the executing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing some refactoring. While Moq doesn't offer support for ref parameters in this scenario, it does work with out parameters.

Here's the refactored function signature:

```
void ParseFirstTwoRows(FileQueue file, out string[] firstRow, out string[] secondRow);
```

And here's the test setup:

```
string[] first = { "'one'", "'two'", "'three'" };
string[] second = { "'one'", "'two'", "'three'" };

Mock<IFileParser> mockFileParse = new Mock<IFileParser>();
mockFileParse.Setup(m => m.ParseFirstTwoRows(It.IsAny<FileQueue>(), out first, out second)).Verifiable();
```

Now when you try and test a function which depends on `ParseFirstTwoRows` the mock will deliver the two specified variables for the `out` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the call back. Just make sure that when you call your SUT that you use the same ref arguments otherwise the call will fail.

Take a look at  the following example using your sample code as reference

```
[TestClass]
public class FileParserTest : MiscMoqTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Moq_With_Ref_Arguents() {
        //Arrange
        Mock<IFileParser> mockFileParse = new Mock<IFileParser>();
        // ref arguments
        string[] firstline = new string[2] { "1", "2" };
        string[] secondline = null;
        // Only matches if the ref arguments to the invocation are the same instance
        mockFileParse.Setup(m => m.ParseFirstTwoRows(It.IsAny<FileQueue>(), ref firstline, ref secondline)).Verifiable();

        var sut = new MyDummyClass(mockFileParse.Object);

        //Act
        sut.DoSomethingWithRef(ref firstline, ref secondline);

        //Assert
        mockFileParse.Verify();
    }

    public class MyDummyClass {
        private IFileParser fileParser;

        public MyDummyClass(IFileParser fileParser) {
            this.fileParser = fileParser;
        }

        public void DoSomethingWithRef(ref string[] firstRow, ref string[] secondRow) {
            var fq = new FileQueue();
            fileParser.ParseFirstTwoRows(fq, ref firstRow, ref secondRow);

        }
    }

    public interface IFileParser {
        void ParseFirstTwoRows(FileQueue file, ref string[] firstRow, ref string[] secondRow);
    }
    public class FileQueue { }
}
```

If however you are not able to supply the same instances for the ref then it doesn't look like you will be able to get a mock to pass successfully. Take a look a the [Quick Start for Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get an understanding of it capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for this, but the call with ref is a private function called from a public one, so I can't pass the params in like that. Hence my problem.

Comment: In that case I would suggest creating your own mock manually for that test and forego Moq for that interface.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you solved your problem by using out parameters instead of ref parameters.

But changing your production code is not the solution, you can use Typemock isolator which allows to create a test with ref parameters:

```
[TestMethod,Isolated]
public void Mocking_With_Ref_Arguments()
{
    // Arrange
    string[] first = { "'one'", "'two'", "'three'" };
    string[] second = { "'one'", "'two'", "'three'" };
    FileQueue file = new FileQueue();
    var classUnderTest = new Class1();

    // What you will set as ref parameters in this line will return as you call the method
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => classUnderTest.ParseFirstTwoRows(file, ref first, ref second)).IgnoreCall();

    // Act
    string[] retFirst = null;
    string[] retSecond = null;
    classUnderTest.someMethod(file, ref retFirst, ref retSecond);

    // Assert
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(first, retFirst);
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(second, retSecond);
}
```